# Different SMTP based on domain

Tags: php, wp-mail, smtp

I have a multi-domain wordpress site, set up so that https://example1.com and https://example2.com both work and show the same content (but with the address bar showing whichever domain was used). I would like admin mails coming from the site to use different SMTP settings depending on the domain (I have completely separate mail accounts in each of the domains that I would like to use to send the respective domain's mail). what is the best way to set something like this up so that it works site-wide depending on the domain?

I can easily setup any of the various SMTP plugins that work with ONE domain...how could I make it work with different settings for EACH?

NOTE: this is not a multisite install. This is ONE site that serves the same content for either domain entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is the [`phpmailer_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init) action hook.

Here is an something you can do.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'custom_smtp_settings' );

function custom_smtp_settings( $phpmailer ) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();

    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

        case 'example1.com': //name only, no http
            $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example1.com';
            $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
            $phpmailer->Port = 25;
            $phpmailer->Username = 'example1';
            $phpmailer->Password = 'example1pass';

            // Additional settings…
            $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
            $phpmailer->From = "admin@example1.com";
            $phpmailer->FromName = "Example One";
            break;

        case 'example2.com':
            $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example2.com';
            $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
            $phpmailer->Port = 25;
            $phpmailer->Username = 'example2';
            $phpmailer->Password = 'example2pass';

            // Additional settings…
            $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
            $phpmailer->From = "admin@example2.com";
            $phpmailer->FromName = "Example Two";
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great, but when I try it I get this error and no sending: `stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1`

Comment: and this is super weird, because my cert is valid and my website serves securely

Comment: I'm not sure why, can you try without SSL to see if that works. That is use 
`$phpmailer->SMTPsecure = ''`

Comment: I can't actually, my mail server requires a secure connection. But the error is on the wordpress server, not my mail server...

Comment: ugh I figured out what was causing the error! `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` does NOT include the http(s). Leaving that off got it working! I credited you with the solution, but you might want to edit that above. Thanks again.